# Eight-hour averages in R studio

Tags: r, average

I want to get eight-hour (Time column) averages of the maximum values of O column. It is important that the time column is each hour of one day. Also, the dataset contains the next columns: (place) several place, (date) 365 days, (Time) per each day it has 24 hours,  (O) values of ozone, month and year.

The sample dataset is:

```
data%>%select("Place","date","Time", "O",
                           "month","year")

Place        Date     Time   O  month    year
Al          2016-01-01  1   23  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  2   15  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  3   18  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  4   18  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  5   20  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  6   21  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  7   24  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  8   24  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  9   22  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  10  24  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  11  33  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  12  53  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  13  54  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  14  54  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  15  58  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  16  60  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  17  57  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  18  55  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  19  50  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  20  51  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  21  51  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  22  55  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  23  46  enero   2016
Al          2016-01-01  24  57  enero   2016
```

I hope to get the maximum values of O column by the period of one day, ie, the 2016-01-01 I want to get eight maximum value of O and make the average.
But I don't know how to do.

Comment: Could you define a bit more average of maximum values? Expected result would help

Comment: I have edited  my post

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zoo::rollapply` for this.

Default usage:

```r
zoo::rollapply(dat$O, 8, max, fill = NA)
#  [1] NA NA NA 24 24 24 33 53 54 54 58 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 57 NA NA NA NA
```

This is "centering" the window, where the first `24` is the max of positions 1-8. I already added `fill=NA`, since we need the output to be the same size as the input vector.

You can change the alignment, so that the max is of the value and 7 to its left or its right. For instance,

```r
zoo::rollapply(dat$O, 8, max, fill = NA, align = "left")
#  [1] 24 24 24 33 53 54 54 58 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 57 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
zoo::rollapply(dat$O, 8, max, fill = NA, align = "right")
#  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 24 24 24 33 53 54 54 58 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 57
```

I'll assume that we need the latter (`align="right"`).

Finally, we can do a partial max, where the second value is the max of indices 1-2; third value is the max of indices 1-3; etc. In that case,

```r
zoo::rollapply(dat$O, 8, max, align = "right", partial = TRUE)
#  [1] 23 23 23 23 23 23 24 24 24 24 33 53 54 54 58 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 57
```

(Notice we don't technically need `fill=NA` anymore.)

If you want "partial" max,